# How do I mock a method of a class' member field?

Tags: java, mockito

I'm using Java 6 and Mockito 1.8.5.  I want to mock a class' member field's method, but I can't figure out how.  I have these classes ...

```
public class CacheService implements CacheCallback {

private final Cache cache;
...

public static CacheService getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
}

private CacheService() {
    cache = new DefaultCacheImpl();
}

public boolean saveNodes(final Map<Long, XmlNode> nodeMap) {
    ...
    cache.saveNodes(nodeMap);
}
...
}


public class DefaultCacheImpl implements Cache {
...
public void saveNodes(Map<Long, XmlNode> xmlNodes) {
    dao.updateDB(xmlNodes);
}
...
}
```

I can't figure out how to mock the "cache" member field's method "saveNodes".  I'm mocking the method below, but because there is no setter in the CacheService class for the field, I can't figure out how to inject my mock ..

```
public class PopulateCacheServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements PopulateCacheService {
...
public Boolean initCache() { 
    boolean ret = false;
    try {
        setupMocks();
        CacheService.getInstance().startCache();
        PopulateCache.addTestEntriesToCache();
        ret = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        ret = false;
    }   // try
    return ret;
}   // initCache

private void setupMocks() { 
    DefaultCacheImpl cache = mock(DefaultCacheImpl.class);
    doAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            return null;  
        }
    }).when(cache).saveNodes(Matchers.anyMap());
}   // setupMocks 

}
```

Are there any other ways to do this with Mockito?  Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in this line:

```
cache = new DefaultCacheImpl();
```

If you construct a cache object inside your CacheService, they are tightly coupled. You can not use the CacheService with another cache implementation.

Instead, pass the cache implementation to the constructor:

```
public CacheService(Cache cacheImpl) {
    this.cache = cacheImpl;
}
```

This allows the CacheService to use any Cache implementation.

Comment: Thanks for this but CacheService is a singleton and currently has a private constructor.  I'm can change the source code, but I still would like only one instance of the CacheService class floating around the jvm.

Comment: @Dave You should seriously consider avoid this static dependency to `CacheService.getInstance()` and use proper DI, so you won't have to hack things here and there just to test. Your design will be much cleaner and elegant too.

Comment: I'm open to what you're saying, but our project forbids the use of 3rd party tools (like Spring) for the core project (for testing its fine).  I'm not in a position to battle my company's policies.  How would you DI with the situation I setup, keeping in mind, I only want one instance of the CacheService object in the JVM?

Comment: I suggest finding out why they're so against 3rd party tools (probably license concerns or support concerns) and try to change their mind. Or find another company who are prepared to let devs get the job done. Or, failing that, do it manually - you don't need tools, just write a boostrapper and knock your classes up from there. Please don't use a massive framework like Spring just for something trivial like DI.

Answer (score 2):

What about making two constructors? The one you have would stay there. Another one would let you pass in the Cache implementation and allow you to test the class. The new constructor can have protected access to limit which classes can use it.

Comment: Or package-private instead of protected.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the source, decopule those classes. Get rid of `cache = new DefaultCacheImpl();` from constructor as Sjoerd suggested.

If you can't - use PowerMock to [mock the constructor](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor) of `DefaultCacheImpl`. I must say that this is really ugly solution (the only uglier is mocking static initialization code).

Note:
Your code is an answer to popular question "Why do I need dependency injection for?". I think people were looking at code like this when they invented DI.

Comment: I like the PowerMock idea b/c I don't have to change the source.  My question is do I have to use the "PrepareForTest" annotation?  The class declaration above ("PopulateCacheServiceImpl") is not a JUnit test class but rather is indirectly invoked by a number of different tests.

Comment: Yes, you have to do the PrepareForTest annotation.  You could also use PowerMock to to mock the static method getInstance() and return a mock instead of the singleton.  I don't think that helps with your problem of multiple instantiation points.